# yii2 how to simplify repetitive code index,ph

Tags: php, yii

new in php and use yii2 as foundation to web development.  please help me to simplify this code, im trying to show in popup ActionColumn buttons e.g. view, update and delete buttons.  here's my code

```
'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'buttons'=>[
    'view'=>function($url,$model){
        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open")></span>',$url,['class'=>'view', 'data-pjax'=>0]);
    },
    'update'=>function($url,$model){
        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil")></span>',$url,['class'=>'update', 'data-pjax'=>0]);
                        }
                    ],
                ],
            ],  
        ]);

    $this->registerJs(
        "$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {  // 'pjax:success' use if you have used pjax
            $('.view').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();      
                    $('#pModal').modal('show')
                                .find('#modalContent')
                                .load($(this).attr('href'));  
            });
        });
    ");

        Modal::begin([
            //'header'=>'<span id="modalHeaderTitle"></span>',
            //'headerOptions'=>['id'=>'modalHeader'],
            'id'=>'pModal',
            'size'=>'modal-lg',
                    //keeps from closing modal with esc key or by clicking out of the modal.
                    // user must click cancel or X to close
                'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => FALSE]
            ]);

            echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";

            Modal::end();


    $this->registerJs(
        "$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {  // 'pjax:success' use if you have used pjax
            $('.update').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();      
                    $('#qModal').modal('show')
                                .find('#modalContent')
                                .load($(this).attr('href'));  
            });
        });
    ");

        Modal::begin([
            //'header'=>'<span id="modalHeaderTitle"></span>',
            //'headerOptions'=>['id'=>'modalHeader'],
            'id'=>'qModal',
            'size'=>'modal-lg',
                    //keeps from closing modal with esc key or by clicking out of the modal.
                    // user must click cancel or X to close
                'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => FALSE]
            ]);

            echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";

            Modal::end()
            ?>
```

please assist me

Comment: What you actually want? If you want single js call just add same class in both button. like `activebtn` and call js on respect of that. But what you want to show in `Modal` content?

Comment: i have 2 inline js for 2 modals, pModal and qModal.  how can i make script that is good for the view and update modal.

Comment: sorry for my comment.  i have thought that since ive tried hard to have single js for two modal.  would it be safe to make a jsfile out of this inline script.  how can i call this external file in my design

Answer (score 0):

```
'buttons'=>[
'view'=>function($url,$model){
    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open")></span>',$url,['class'=>'view action-btn', 'data-pjax'=>0]);
},
'update'=>function($url,$model){
    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil")></span>',$url,['class'=>'update action-btn', 'data-pjax'=>0]);
                    }
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

`action-btn` added for both button. Now call a ajax from your view and write your modal code in there.

```
$this->registerJs( "$.ajax({
           url: '$url',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {  },
           success: function(data) { 
            //your code                       
           }
        });");
```

`$url = \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/your-action-here']);` 
Write `modal` code on the view file you are redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
'buttons' => [
    'view' => function ($url, $model) {
        return Html::a(
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open")></span>',
            $url,
            [
                'class' => 'openModal', 
                'data-pjax' => 0
            ]
        );
    },
    'update' => function ($url, $model) {
        return Html::a(
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil")></span>',
            $url,
            [
                'class' => 'openModal', 
                'data-pjax' => 0
            ]
        );
    },
]
```

**Modal**

```
Modal::begin([
    'id' => 'modal-popup',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'backdrop' => 'static', 
        'keyboard' => FALSE
    ]
]);
echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
Modal::end();
```

**JS**

```
$this->registerJs(
    "$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function() {
        $('.openModal').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();      
            $('#modal-popup').modal('show').find('#modalContent').load($(this).attr('href'));  
        });
    });
");
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask more? How can I make this inline js as external js cause i will be using it many times?  how do i call it?

Comment: I had created  component for this, unfortunately it's not uploaded any where, give some time, i will share a gist.

Comment: @CristinaJesuitas. [Modal Widget](https://gist.github.com/InsaneSkull/9aa45b0bf7a7c1a64098e59c1d405308). This is pretty poor widget, don't use it, but you will get the idea how to write common js for all.